# Injecting Request scope bean through constructor using annotation or Java config without xml config

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, spring-boot, spring-rest

I created a sample Spring boot rest app with the following controller, service and bean code.

```
@RestController
public class SampleController {

    @Autowired
    SampleService sampleService;

    @Autowired
    User user;

    @ResponseBody
    @GetMapping(value="/user/add")
    public String addUser(User user) {
        return sampleService.getUserName();
    }
}

@Component
public class SampleService {


    private User user;

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    @Required
    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return "user name is "+this.getUser();
    }
}

@RequestScope
@Component
public class User {

    private String username;

    private String password;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}

@Configuration
public class RequestBean {

    @Bean
    @Scope(scopeName = "request", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
    public User initUser() {
        User user = new User();
        return user;
    }
}
```

When I start the spring boot app, I am getting this below error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'sampleController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sampleService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sampleService' defined in file [<path>\samplespringrest\target\classes\com\example\SampleService.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Property 'user' is required for bean 'sampleService'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:569) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:349) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1219) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:751) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at com.example.SamplespringrestApplication.main(SamplespringrestApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sampleService' defined in file [<path>/SampleService.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Property 'user' is required for bean 'sampleService'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:207) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1128) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1056) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:566) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Property 'user' is required for bean 'sampleService'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:156) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1219) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
```

Please help me to solve this.

Thanks in advance.

***Update***

After I update my service class like the one below

```
@Component
public class SampleService {

    @Autowired
    private User user;

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return "user name is "+this.getUser().getUsername();
    }
}
```

I am getting response as "user name is null"

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have restricted lifecycle of User bean by request scope and at the same time using **@Required** for its setter in SampleService. So you haven't got any request at application starting time -> user bean didn't create -> required annotation thrown Exception. It's clear from @RequestScope annotation docs:

> {@code @RequestScope} is a specialization of {@link Scope @Scope} for
>   a  * component whose lifecycle is bound to the current web request.

So you configuration provoked this exception.

Comment: What response do you expect? You just have injected User field, but property of this class can be null.  > this.getUser().getUsername();  this means you username is null, is it incorrect? Check your constructor actually: new User(). Does it set username?

Comment: Actually I am trying to inject User bean with request scope to SampleService class instead of setting manually or passing as an argument to method.

Comment: I need to pass User object to service class from controller class.  Instead of just setting via method or passing as an argument to method I am trying to inject.  It is possible right?

Comment: Looks like your don't understand your code :  @Autowired
    User user;

    ResponseBody
    GetMapping(value="/user/add")
    public String addUser(User user) {
        return sampleService.getUserName();
    }
Your inject bean in controller but at the same time you get it as parameter and try to get User from your service. It looks really weird. So problem is in your logic and configuration

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125272/discussion-between-sergii-getman-and-mvg).